# How to assert concrete type based on error

Tags: go, type-assertion

How to assert a variable is of concrete type and not of base type?

```
import "errors"
import "fmt"

type NotFound error

func test() {
    e := errors.New("some error")
    notFound := NotFound(errors.New("404"))
    
    _, ok := notFound.(NotFound) //returns true as expected
    _, isNotFound := e.(NotFound) //returns true, but i'm expecting false
 
}
```

Is there a way to assert only the concrete type and not the base type?

Link to the playground : https://play.golang.org/p/qXYZlbKR92l

NotFound is an interface type as mentioned in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NotFound` is not a concrete type. Both `error` and `NotFound` are interface types. They are both defined as interfaces containing `Error() string` method, and thus, they are equivalent. The same type assertion would not work with non-interface types.

Comment: So is there a way to check the type?

Comment: `e.(NotFound)` means "does e implement NotFound", because NotFound is an interface. Either declare a `NotFound = errors.New("Not found")` and check `err==NotFound`, or declare a concrete `type NotFound struct{}` with `Error() string` method, so you can use  type-assertion.

Comment: Understood. Forgot that error is an interface and not a struct. Thanks for the explanation. I changed the type to a struct with an error variable and now the assertion works